# Sum of primes below 2 million

Tags: c

What am i doing wrong here?

```
  #include<stdio.h>

    int main(){
        int i,count;
        long long int sum = 0, num;

        for(num = 1; num <= 1000; num++){
            count = 0;
            for(i = 2; i <= num / 2; i++){
                if(num % i == 0){
                    count++;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(count == 0 && num != 1)
                sum = sum + num;
        }
        printf("Sum of prime numbers is: %d ", sum);
        return 0;
    }
```

I tried to make a program that outputs the sum of all primes below nth number, n being 2 million however when i try to run it, there is a slight delay and it outputs nothing... it works well enough  for small numbers like 1000 or 100 but big numbers it just does not output anything.There are no error or bugs that i know of either. (please help, i know nothing, so guide this young one)

Comment: Some things take time...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sum of primes below two million. Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6176126/sum-of-primes-below-two-million-sieve-of-eratosthenes)

Comment: Your code uses undefined behaviour since you messed up the format string for printf: prime.c:16:12: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘long long int’ [-Wformat=]
     printf("Sum of prime numbers is: %d ",sum);

Comment: Can you format your code so that it is easier to read? Right now, it looks messy.

Answer (score 1):

The above program is fine, but it is possible to further reduce the time complexity and make it faster.
 The better approach is to use **sieve of eratosthenes** algorithm.
You can read about it here http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sieve-of-eratosthenes/ 
The program for your problem is

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

void SieveOfEratosthenes(long long int n)
{

    bool prime[n+1];
    memset(prime, true, sizeof(prime));

    for (long long int p=2; p*p<=n; p++)
    {
        if (prime[p] == true)
        {
                 for (int i=p*2; i<=n; i += p)
                prime[i] = false;
        }
    }

 long long sum=0;
        for (int p=2; p<=n; p++)
       if (prime[p])
          sum+=p;
          cout << sum << " ";
}


int main()
{
    int n = 2000000;
    cout << "sum of prime numbers less then 2000000 is :" << endl;
    SieveOfEratosthenes(n);
    return 0;
}
```

Please let me know if you face difficulty in understanding the program.
**Note:** You can also use **Segmented seive** to further reduce the time complexity

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int main(){
int i,count;
long long int sum=0, num;
for(num = 1;num<=1000000;num++){
 count = 0;
for(i=2;i<=sqrt(num);i++){         //change here
if(num%i==0){
 count++;
 break;
  }
  }
     if(count==0 && num!= 1)
      sum = sum + num;
      }
  printf("Sum of prime numbers is: %lld ",sum);   //and here
     return 0;
    }
```

Some simple maths, while checking for prime, check up to square root of a number. And in printf() the format specifier for long long int is %lld not %d.

Comment: While it speeds things up considerably it changes nothing. The code was valid before (apart from the %lld). Note: `sqrt(num)` is expensive, `num >= i * i` is faster.

Comment: sieve-of-eratosthenes is a better approach

Comment: @TanujYadav yep